# Strange boost circular buffer behaviour after calling linearize

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

I have implemented an extract method over my `boost::circular_buffer`, which just copies `n` elements to a `destination` vector, and then removes those n elements from the circular buffer (so its internal pointers are updated, marking where it can be written again):

```
void CircularBuffer::extract(const unsigned int n, vector<complex<float>> *destination){
    // Wait until the buffer is not empty
    std::unique_lock<mutex> l(lock);
    notEmpty.wait(l, [this, n](){
        return (int)(circularBuffer.size() - n) >= 0;
    });

    // We must copy n elements from a linearized version of the buffer
    memcpy(destination, circularBuffer.linearize(), n);
    // Remove extracted elements from circular buffer
    circularBuffer.erase(circularBuffer.begin(), circularBuffer.begin() + n); //SIGSEGV

    // Not full any more
    notFull.notify_one();
}
```

When `erase` method is called, I get a segmentation fault.

I am using the following sizes:

```
n = 9000
circularBuffer.size() = 9000 (at the moment when extract method is called)
circularBUffer.capacity() = 90000
```

But, as soon as the `memcpy` line is executed, and I guess because of the `linearize` call, everything is messed and the debugger shows:

```
circularBuffer.size() = 3238197033 (Hex: Hex:0xc102f729)
circularBUffer.capacity() = 18446744073434141805 (Hex:0xffffffffef95946d)
```

I might have not understood how the linearize method works, but it looks quite strange anyway.

If I go on, and the erase method is called, the segmentation fault is raised and the program ends. I could understand it if I were erasing more data than the buffer capacity, but it is not the case.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your memcpy is wrong. You are copying the data into the address of the `vector` object itself instead of copying it to a place pointed by the vector. Make sure `vector::reserve` is called before calling this function to avoid unnecessary memory de-alloc and allocation.

I would rewrite the function as:

```
    #include <iterator>

    void CircularBuffer::extract(const unsigned int n, 
                               vector<complex<float>>& destination)
    {
        // Wait until the buffer is not empty
        std::unique_lock<mutex> l(lock);
        notEmpty.wait(l, [this, n](){
            return (int)(circularBuffer.size() - n) >= 0;
        });

        auto cb_ptr = circularBuffer.linearize();
        assert (cb_ptr);

        std::copy(cb_ptr, cb_ptr + n, std::back_inserter(destination));

        circularBuffer.erase(circularBuffer.begin(), circularBuffer.begin() + n); 

        // Not full any more
        notFull.notify_one();
    }
```

Comment: Strangely, if I use reserve(1000), the vector gets its current size incremented by 1000, which is not the expected result as described in cppreference. Anyway, your code has solved my bug, so thanks!